# Font rendering inconsistently on PC

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm using the `bodonixt` font for a website, and if the font size is set to less than 24.5px, the font is uneven. If I view the site on a Mac, the font is okay, on PC it isn't. It looks weird on all browsers too. Is there any way I can fix this with css?

You can see what I mean here: www.fredgranados.com

Comment: I've only ever loaded a new font 2 or 3 times, so I'm not 100% confident that I know what I'm talking about - However, looking at the CSS, there's an inconsistency with the font I've never seen before, i.e. the massive chunk of code for woff.  My apologies if this is right but I've never seen it like that before!  Just an idea at a quick glance!

http://www.fredgranados.com/themes/bootstrap_theme/css/styles.css

Comment: Yes, that is because it's base64 encoded. I had to do that to get the font to work on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the font is hinted (optimized). A font is a series of vector images. The vector shape doesn't necessarily fit to exact pixels, so the browser/OS/renderer should determine whether a pixel should become black or white (or a shade of grey, in case of anti-aliasing). To do this right, the font can contain [Hinting information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), which helps the renderer making the right choices when drawing the font. Often, fonts are only optimized (hinted) for specific font sizes, and specific targets, because this process is expensive and hard, and also makes the font file larger.

I've downloaded the Bodoni XT font on DaFont, and I wasn't really impressed by the quality of the smaller sizes when opening it in the font previewer in Windows. For instance, the serifs of some letters were completely missing in smaller sizes.

In general, it looks like this font just isn't made too well, or it is only optimized for printing and/or displaying in large font sizes.

Maybe the font is better optimized for Mac, or the Mac is better at displaying fonts like these. Anyway, if you would like this to work on other OSes as well, you'll need a better version, or a different font altogether. I've inspected some other fonts by [Manfred Klein](http://www.dafont.com/manfred-klein.d302), and most of his serif fonts seem to have similar issues when displayed in smaller sizes.

Comment: Kerning doesn't have a whole lot to do with this. Yes, kerning will impact where along a 'pixel' the vector may align, but it's not like you can easily kern it to align on the pixel to begin with. Kerning is really just an aesthetic call for general spacing.

Comment: @DA. I think you're right about kerning. I thought there was a word for what I meant, but don't recall what it was.. Anyway, I've removed 'kerning' from my answer, since that is obviously the wrong term.

Comment: Yes, hinting (or rather, lack thereof) can definitely be the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

Is it a webfont? Meaning you're loading it via CSS? If so, that's just how it is. Every browser, every OS, every user set of system and/or user preferences may cause the font to render slightly differently.

If it's not a webfont, the same issues as above apply, but you have the added issue that not everyone will necessarily have that font installed, or if they do, they may have a different version of the font.

Comment: I don't know that it's defined as a web font. I do load it via css and @font-family though.

Comment: @Blaine not so much a difference as just more variances. I've updated my answer. Bottom line: Don't expect typography to look exactly the same across all browsers and devices. Allow for variance.

Comment: Oh, if you load it via CSS that that's typically considered a 'web font'.

Comment: Does the fact that it looks the same at a specific size mean anything? When I set the font-size to 24.5px, it works as it should.

Comment: I don't know off-hand if browsers use hinting, but if so, that could be what you are seeing. Hinting is creating a screen-optimized bitmap at certain font sizes. If the hinting is there the bitmaps are used. Otherwise, the browser is drawing them itself. If the browser does obey font hinting, then the same set of bitmaps would be used for that particular font size and wouldn't be subject to the same idiosyncrasies as if the browser was rendering the bitmap itself.

Comment: If that is the case, is there anything I can do to change it; or, am I just stuck?

Comment: You could open the font in a font editing tool and manually hint it for every size you want to use it at, but that's not really a practical solution. All that said, you are using Bodoni at a rather small size. Bodoni--at least on screen--is really a display typeface. It has really thin parts and needs to be larger for it to really look good. I'd suggest just making your headers quite a bit bigger (at least 40px) or consider a different typeface that doesn't have quite the contrast between thick and thin strokes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It has been very helpful and appreciated.